# Working with Java Swing, button that activates reader won't display the needed labels?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, bufferedreader

I'm reading from a text file a long quote, so all the labels are set but the button will not display a `JLabel` of the thing. I can get the system print to display but the labels wouldn't come out so the button seems to be fine. To be very specific the quote is an "html formatted text document of chris tucker's version of martin luther king speech.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
package MenuBoxes;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class quoteReader extends JFrame{
    private JFrame frame;
public quoteReader(){
    initUI();
}
public final void initUI(){ {
    String listArray[] = null;
    JButton click = new JButton("click me");
    click.setLocation(120,30);
    click.setSize(100,100);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(click);
    add(panel);
    setTitle("Quote Reader");
    setSize(500,400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
click.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //nameLabel = name.getText();
        //use .= for comparing strings
        String[] listArray = new String [2];
        try{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Chrt\\workspace\\Finals\\Quotes.txt"));
            int index = 0;
            String line = "";
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              listArray[index] = line;
                index++;
                JLabel read = new JLabel(line);
                System.out.println(line);
                read.setLocation(120,90);
                read.setSize(300,200);
                read.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,13));
                panel.add(read);
                add(panel);
                setVisible(true);
            }
            br.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe){
                System.out.println("Cannot read");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            }
    }
);

}}}
```

Comment: Just a thought: it wouldn't be better use [JEditorPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) instead of a bunch of `JLabels`? Besides, you shouldn't use methods such as `setBounds(...)`, `setLocation(...)` not `setXxxSize(...)` because Swing is designed to be used with [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and not fixed component size/location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repaint after adding text to the label.

```
this.repaint();
```

Also, per your code, you aren't making the JFrame visoble until AFTER you add text to the JLabel.  you should add

```
setVisible(true);
```

to your initUI() method.